# Can't output data inside angular-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to make an angular-repeat inside another angular repeat. If I write:

{{field.labels}}
It outputs an array like this:

```
[{"name":"media","label":"Media"},{"name":"frilans","label":"Frilans"}]
```

If I try something really simple, like

```
<fieldset
    class="options"
    ng-repeat="mylabel in field.labels"
>


    <input type="radio" >{{mylabel}}
</fieldset>
```

It seems to be working, because the number of input-tags correspond to the number of items in the array, but It won't output {{mylabel}}. Why?

Here is a complete sample of the code:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FEyir

Here is the complete field-variable, `.options` is only used when type=radio: `ng-switch-when="radio"`

```
    fields:
        [
            {
                label: 'First Name',
                name: 'firstname',
                key: '',
                type: 'text',
                //fixa requierd i templatesen
                required: true
            },
            {
                label: 'Last Name',
                name: 'lastname',
                key: '',
                required: true,
            },
            {
                label: 'Email',
                name: 'email',
                key: '',
                required: true,
                type: 'email',
            },
            {
                key: '',
                type: 'radio',
                labels:
                [
                    {
                        name: 'media',
                        label: 'Media'
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'frilans',
                        label: 'Frilans'

                    }

                ],
            }
        ],

    },
```

Comment: Should't this be `<input type="radio" >{{mylabel.label}}`?

Comment: that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<fieldset
class="options"
ng-repeat="mylabel in field.labels">


<input type="radio" >{{mylabel}}
</fieldset>
```

Replcae To:

```
<!--radiobuttons-->
<fieldset ng-switch-when="radio" class="options">

       <span ng-repeat="mylabel in field.labels">
          <input type="radio" > {{mylabel.label}}
        </span>
  </fieldset>
```

[codepen code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Bahcs)

Comment: Nope, that doesn't output anything either. That isn't to weird, as {{mylabel}} seems to be empty, it ougth to output an object,

Comment: i need data of field variable